# How to handle transformation failure

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have json embedded in string, and parsing from string fails. I'd like to create nice validation error for my backend, but instead validator throws exception from validation function (i.e. I'm getting Json parse exception, instead of ValidationException).

Example:

```
    public class Validator: AbstractValidator<MyDto>
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            Transform(dto => dto.StrJsonProp, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnotherDto>);
        }
    }

    new Validator().Validate(new MyDto(){StrJsonProp = null;});
    // Throws exception "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')" from StringReader.ctor
```